# Django model TextField display zip code format

Tags: python, django

In my `models.py`, I have a zip code field that are in `TextField` format:

```py
class Merged(models.Model):
    zip_code = models.TextField(db_column='Zip Code', blank=True, null=True)
```

However, there exists some invalid zip codes like

```
sagaponack 11962
lindenhurst 11757
```

I just want to display the 5-digit zip code without any other texts.

### What I have tried and failed

In `serializers.py`, I tried to apply a `RegexField` to the `zip_code` column:

```py
class MergedSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    zip_code = serializers.RegexField(regex=r'^\d{5}')
    class Meta:
        model = Merged
        fields = '__all__'
```

It did not work.

How do I solve this in a way that does not only change how it displays, but also ensures that sorting works properly (i.e. ignore the text part, only sort based on zip codes)

Answer (score 0):

Model.clean() is a method of Model class where can provide a custom validation for your model you can see all the methods and properties of Model clas in this link [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/][1]

```
class Article(models.Model):
    def clean(self): 
      /*** your validations **/
```

if you wanted to separate the validation for models you can go after through ModelForm class which is much better than Model class

```
class UserFields(forms.ModelForm):
     
   def clean_contact_number(self):
        contact_number = self.cleaned_data.get('contact_number')
        if ' ' in contact_number:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Should not have blank spaces included')
        if not str(contact_number).isdigit():
            raise forms.ValidationError('Should not have letters or special characters included')
            pass
        return contact_number

        pass
```

There so may ways to do the custom validation in the Django, even serializers class has own method for validation

```
class BoxSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Box
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'url', 'title')

    def validate(self, data):
        if self.instance: # 'instance' will be set in case of `PUT` request i.e update
            object_id = self.instance.id # get the 'id' for the instance
            # write your validation logic based on the object id here

        return data

   def validate_title(self, value):
       """
      Check that the blog post is about Django.
      """
       if 'django' not in value.lower():
          raise serializers.ValidationError("Blog post is not about Django")
       return value
```

Comment: Hey Mark, thanks for the answer. Is this for validating the new entries? My database won't be accepting new entries... I was asking if there's a way to deal with current data. Thank you.